# Ошибка загрузки изображения. CORS

Tags: flutter, dart

Передаю в Image.network такую ссылку: https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffffff/000000?text=No+Photo. Изображение не загружается, вместо него заглушка. В консоли ошибка:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffffff/000000?text=No+Photo' from origin 'http://localhost:52395' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Получилось проксировать запрос:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NetworkProxyImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String src;

  NetworkProxyImage({required this.src});
  
  Future<http.Response> _fetch() async {
    var uri = Uri(
      scheme: 'https',
      host: 'api.allorigins.win',
      path: '/raw',
      queryParameters: {
        'url': src,
      }
    );

    return await http.get(uri);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(future: _fetch(), builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container();
      }

      return Image.memory(snapshot.data!.bodyBytes);
    });
  }
}
```

Наверное не лучший способ, но другого не нашел...